# Linq queries references different contexts but actually it is not

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to get data from two different tables using EF 6, it is a asp.net mvc 5 project with Identity 2.0 used in it, however when i join two tables, i am getting the error that contexts of both entities are different, however it is not, here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserAccountStatus> UserAccountStatuss { get; set;}

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
       return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

and here is my linq query :

```
var result = (from user in DbContext.Users
              join accountStatus in DbContext.UserAccountStatuss on user.Id equals accountStatus.UserId
              where user.Email == email
              select accountStatus.AccountEnabled).FirstOrDefault();
```

My DbContext property:

```
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
{
    get
    {
        return _dbContext ?? ApplicationDbContext.Create();
    }
    private set
    {
        _dbContext = value;
    }

}
```

Exact error is :

> > The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

and this is not a duplicate, i have seen other questions, in those user are actually trying different contexts, but in my case i have one.

Comment: Seems like your `DBContext` is getting instantiated twice. Can you verify how your instantiation logic is working?

Comment: @CamBruce it is posted in the question,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your lazy instantiaiton is the problem. It should be

```
private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
{
    get
    {
        if(_dbContext==null){_dbContext=ApplicationDbContext.Create();}
        return _dbContext;
    }


}
```

Edit: Example with Lazy

```
private Lazy<ApplicationDbContext> _dbContext=new Lazy<ApplicationDbContext>(()=>ApplicationDbContext.Create());
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
{
    get
    {
        return _dbContext.Value;
    }


}
```

Comment: No problem. I actually usually like to use Lazy<T> for simple stuff like this, but getting it to function correctly in multi threaded environments is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
{
    get
    {
        return _dbContext ?? ApplicationDbContext.Create();
    }
    private set
    {
        _dbContext = value;
    }

}
```

You get a new context every time...

```
public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
{
    get
    {
        if(_dbContext == null)
            _dbContext = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
        return _dbContext;
    }    
}
```

Try this

Comment: I think the condition should be `== null`

Comment: my bad, my mind is out mind today :P thanks for pointing my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your property will return a new context each time it is accessed.
You need to store the newly created context so it can be returned the next time it is used.